# Wordpress Enqueue Js scripts

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I am having trouble getting wp_enqueue functions to work. I've looked at all the documentation on it but am having trouble sifting through and finding out what is supposed to go where.

so far I understand that I am supposed to register and enqueue the files from the functions.php file of the theme I am creating. So that is exactly what I do. I create some PHP tags and drop it in the middle of them, at the bottom of the page. Save and Upload.

When I reload, it just returns a blank white screen, must be an error in the code or something.

Here is the function:

```
<?php
function add_scripts(){
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js');
wp_register_script('nivo', get_bloginfo('url').'/scripts/nivo.js');
wp_register_script('slimbox',get_bloginfo('url').'/scripts/slimbox2.js');
wp_register_script('picasa', get_bloginfo('url').'/scripts/jquery.EmbedPicasaGallery.js');
wp_register_script('pwi',get_bloginfo('url').'/jquery.pwi-min.js');
wp_register_script('swf', get_bloginfo('url').'/jquery.swfobject.1-1-1.min.js');
wp_register_script('simpletube',get_bloginfo('url').'/scripts/jquery.simpletube.js');
wp_register_script('jqvalidate', get_bloginfo('url').'/jquery.jqvalidate.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('nivo');
wp_enqueue_script('slimbox');
wp_enqueue_script('picasa');
wp_enqueue_script('pwi')
wp_enqueue_script('swf');
wp_enqueue_script('simpletube')
wp_enqueue_script('jqvalidate');
}

add_action('init','add_scripts');
?>
```

So is there some sort of problem with my syntax? I'm not that strong with PHP.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You've got two `wp_enqueue_script('picasa');`, missing a `wp_enqueue_script('nivo');`.

Comment: Thanks, I dont think that is the problem though. I fixed that and still the same result

Comment: See my answer below. You're missing some semi-colons (`;`) in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of hard to debug it without seeing the whole file but the fact you get a 'blank page' suggests there's definitely something larger than a syntax problem somewhere.

Do you definitely have correctly nested php tags?  i.e.

```
<?php

some code

<?php

some more code

?>

some more code

?>
```

will give you problems.

Also, it's now common practice to leave the last `?>` from the end of the file (it means you wont have any issues with having whitespace after the closing tags and they're not necessary)

On top of that, you've used `wp_register_script('jquery'...)` - WordPress already has jquery registered. If you wish to re-register it, you need to `wp_deregister_script('jquery')` first. I'd also only do that *outside* of the admin, so:

`if(!is_admin()){wp_deregister_script('jquery'); <your wp_register_script stuff> }`

If these things don't help, copy and paste your entire `functions.php` file (use pastebin.com and give us a link)

As an aside, you're using `get_bloginfo('url')` several times - which means you're running lots of unnecessary calls to the database. Stick it into a variable and save yourself a little overhead:

```
$my_url = get_bloginfo('wpurl');

wp_register_script('thing', $my_url.'/script/location/file.js');
```

Oh! One more thing, I don't think `url` is an allowed argument for `get_bloginfo()` I think you want `wpurl`

[Codex page on get_bloginfo() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Missing `;` for the following two lines:

```
wp_enqueue_script('pwi')
wp_enqueue_script('simpletube')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your code I would use:

```
<?php
function add_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('nivo', get_bloginfo('url').'/scripts/nivo.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('slimbox',get_bloginfo('url').'/scripts/slimbox2.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('picasa', get_bloginfo('url').'/scripts/jquery.EmbedPicasaGallery.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('pwi',get_bloginfo('url').'/jquery.pwi-min.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('swf', get_bloginfo('url').'/jquery.swfobject.1-1-1.min.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('simpletube',get_bloginfo('url').'/scripts/jquery.simpletube.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('jqvalidate', get_bloginfo('url').'/jquery.jqvalidate.js'); 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
```

So please notice I have removed "wp_register_script" as using that is totally unnecessary if you are going to call wp_enqueue immediately after register.

```
wp_register_script
```

Is used so that you can afterwards call it ANYWHERE else in code without including the path.

Also big change is that I'm not calling the function from

```
init
```

But I'm calling it from

```
wp_enqueue_scripts
```

Also please consider adding additional parameters to your wp_enqueue_script such as

```
wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```